# Ubuntu перейти в папку с названием на русском языке

Tags: ubuntu, кодировка, консоль, terminal

Как в *Ubuntu* в консольном режиме (только английский язык) перейти в папку с русским названием?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 22):

варианты без перенастройки средств ввода:

1. запустите (предварительно установив, если не установлен, и есть такая возможность) какой-нибудь файловый менеджер: `mc`, `lfm`, `vifm`, `ranger` и т.п.
2. если установлен `vim` (не `vi`!) и надо отредактировать какой-то файл, то можно им и воспользоваться как файловым менеджером: `vim .` — программа запустится в режиме [*netrw*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075) (по умолчанию этот скрипт, вроде бы, установлен в *ubuntu*), где можно будет «перейти» к любому файлу/каталогу.

   нажатие <kbd>enter</kbd> будет интерпретировано для каталога — как `cd`, для файла — открытие его для редактирования.
3. если установлен `emacs`, можно воспользоваться его пакетом [*dired* — directory editor](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html).
4. на самый крайний (зато абсолютно универсальный) случай можно воспользоваться конструкцией `cd "$(...)"`, где вместо `...` должна идти команда, возвращающая имя нужного каталога (кавычки нужны для тех случаев, когда в названии каталога есть пробелы).

   это может быть, например, команда `ls | sed -n 2p`, где `2` — номер нужного каталога в выдаче `ls`.

   посмотреть пронумерованную выдачу `ls` можно, например, так:

   ```
   $ ls | nl
        1  bin
        2  boot
        3  dev
        4  etc
   ...
   ```

   т.е., для перехода в каталог `boot` надо выполнить:

   ```
   $ cd "$(ls | sed -n 2p)"
   ```

Comment: Кстати, прочитал сегодня, что вы все голоса тратите на разбор неоцененных ответов. Спасибо, это очень ценное дело. Я вот не успеваю уже туда заглядывать. И за обновление статистики тоже спасибо!

Comment: подход в ответе пытается обойти проблему, вместо того чтобы её решить -- настроить обычное окружение, чтобы Unicode нормально воспринимался, например, можно смотреть на русские (китайские, японские, какие хотите) буквы в С.UTF-8 локали. Из вопроса не ясно в чём проблема (может кто-то зашёл по ssh на систему и у них locale не настроилась  и поэтому POSIX locale используется по умолчанию и соответственно только ASCII позволяет вводить).

Comment: @jfs, с удовольствием прочитаю и проголосую за ваш вариант ответа.

Comment: для ответа в вопросе не хватает деталей (он слишком общий и поздно уже его менять). Цель моего комментария, чтобы люди слишком не увлекались решениями, представленными в вашем ответе, а решали корневую проблему (Ubuntu замечательно Unicode поддерживает). Например, хотя у меня [](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol) не отображается как флаг (шрифт наверно не стоит подходящий), но Chromium понимает, что это один символ, а не два или 8.

Comment: Менять что-то не всегда есть возможность. Например, вы решаете проблему через TeamViewer. У клиента немецкая расскладка, он в свою очередь подоючен к KVM, где настройки норвежские. Вот тут вспомнишь еще не один хак.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо, начал добавлять отсылку, к кому обращаюсь в комментариях.  Я попробовал ваш пример с переходом по номеру, удобно. Добавил, правда, ключ -F (ls -F | nl), а то при листинге не понятно это файл или директория.

Answer (score 7):

Настройте поддержку русского языка в консоли:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Ну а дальше просто:

```bash
cd /папка/с/русским/названием/
```

Ну или тупо перебирайте варианты при помощи автодополнения(tab-ом). Однако это неудобно, да и без шрифта поддерживающего кирилицу(настраивается в console-setup) вы русские названия всё равно нормально не увидите.

Comment: А просто `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` не поможет?

Comment: @installero, к данному случаю локаль не имеет отношения.

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov не верно, экранировать как будете (имеются в виду пробелы)? откуда известна кодировка терминала? как узнавать будем? как ранее комментировали некоторые (они поймут): учите матчасть

Answer (score 2):

Если консоль поддерживает выделение и вставку, можно вывести список директорий, выделить нужную и вставить после команды `cd`

Comment: а если мыши нету?

Comment: @айтишник тогда воспользуйтесь другим ответом или напишите свой. Зачем же все ответы минусовать

Answer (score 0):

После cd, не нажимая пробел, табом можно накликать нужное название на русском. Получится, что то вроде такого cd \ название_на_русском/
Такая команда не работает на mac:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup

Answer (score 0):

На Windows c табом всё работает. Вот как я решил проблему.
Сначала вводил, терминал ругался:
cd C:\Us\Gig\OnDve\Рабочий стол\Jupyter

А если так ввести в кавычках, терминал всё принял:
cd 'C:\Us\Gig\OnDve\Рабочий стол\Jupyter'

Comment: Во-первых, первоначальный вопрос относится к Ubuntu, а не к Windows.  Во-вторых, ваша "проблема" состояла в пробеле внутри пути `Рабочий стол`, и для таких путей требуется использовать кавычки.

Answer (score 0):

добавлю в копилку

переход с помощью утилиты [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

```
cd "`ls|fzf`"
```

можно и стандартными средствами через `inode`. Для простоты создадим функцию `cdi`

```
cdi(){ cd "$(ls -1id */ |awk -v i=$1 '$1==i' |cut -d ' ' -f 2-)";}
```

для удобства можно поместить её в `~/.bashrc`

теперь чтобы перейти в нужную нам папку для начала смотрим какой у неё `inode`

```
ls -1id */
```

`inode` отобразиться в первом столбце

допустим что `inode` будет `35463`, тогда просто выполняем команду

```
cdi 35463
```