# Несуществующий файл без индексации(GIT)

Tags: git

Появился файл с невозможным именем,который стоит не проиндексированным[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удалить его невозможно - путь к нему не существующий.

Как избавиться от этой аномалии? Cначала старался не обращать внимания, но за несколько дней уже начало раздражать. Подскажите, как разобраться.

Comment: пробывали git rm?

Comment: @SergeiStralenia, эм.... а вы пост читали? "Удалить его не возможно-путь к нему не существующий". из этой фразы как бы вытекает что я пробовал его ремувнуть...

Comment: Вы бы написали что пробывали, а что нет, удалить понятие растяжимое. Перечеслите, что вы побывали: git rm, git-clean может еще что

Comment: текст всё-таки лучше вставлять в вопросы/ответы в виде текста, а не картинки.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> путь к нему не существующий

я думаю, файл такой всё-таки существует. в каталоге `upload`.

и называется он:

```
$ echo "arrow - \320\272\320\276\320\277\320\270\321\217.png" | sed 's/\\/\\\\0/g' | xargs echo -e
arrow - копия.png
```

файл этот не входит в репозиторий — он *untracked* (*неотслеживаемый*), поэтому пытаться применить к нему `git rm ...` или что-то подобное — бессмысленно. если он вам не нужен, его имеет смысл удалить (программой `rm`).

если у вас проблемы с отображением/вводом в кодировке *utf8*, можете воспользоваться вот [этим советом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451154/178576), только вместо `cd` воспользуйтесь: сначала `ls`, а затем, когда убедитесь, что указываете на нужный файл, и `rm`.

---

совет: пробелы в именах файлов/каталогов для обращения к ним в командной строке надо экранировать обратным слэшем. например:

```
$ rm arrow\ -\ копия.png
```

---

**дополнение**

по умолчанию программа `git` отображает символы юникода в именах файлов в виде *quoted string* (как в вопросе).

отключается такое преобразование изменением конфигурации (вероятно, начиная с версии 1.7.10):

```
$ git config [--global] core.quotepath off
```

Comment: да,есть (был теперь уже) файл arrow - копия.png . даже не знал что баш не может нормально отображать кириллицу. Спасибо

Comment: это вы про вывод команды `git status`? тут претензии — к [программе *git*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22828826/4827341).

Comment: да. Когда понял что проблема с выводом кириллицы-немного в ступор впал) использую GIT Bash