# Русификация git в консоли

Tags: git, кириллица, локализация, source-tree

Windows 10 корпоративная (толи русская, толи с MUI) + [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

При работе из командной строки кириллица отображается через бэкслеш:

```
c:\somegitrepo>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   "\320\236\321\202\320\277\321\203\321\201\320\272\320\260/2018Otpusk 2018\321\20501.doc"

c:\somegitrepo
```

Это можно как-то исправить настройками операционки, либо настройками самого git, либо задать на уровне конкретного репозитория?

Хотелось бы видеть:

```
C:\somegitrepo>git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        Отпуска/Otpusk 2018х01.doc

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

В контрольной панели в Региональных параметрах стоит "Текущий язык программ, не поддерживающих Юникод" - Русский (Россия).

Аналогичные проблемы при работе из консоли Source Tree, выбрана настройка "Use System Git".

Comment: "Русская" и "с MUI" - это одно и то же, слово "русская" лишь указывает какой языковой пакет включен для вашего пользователя. Кажется, начиная не то с висты, не то с семерки других вариантов локализации кроме MUI нет.

Comment: используйте баш консоль вместо виндовой.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456445/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Мне нравится способ `git config [--global] core.quotepath off` (репозиториев с кириллицей у меня немного). Впишите ответ, поставлю галку. Баш консоль наверное тоже сработает, но я не привык ей пользоваться под виндой.

Comment: @AK, хорошо, напишу.

Comment: https://mirrors.ehttps://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html dge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html

Comment: Обе ссылки не открываются, первая ещё и криво вставлена

Answer (score 29, accepted):

по умолчанию программа *git* при выводе путей (команды типа `state`, `ls-files`, `diff` и т.п.) символы с кодом больше `0x80` заменяет их восьмиричными кодами (например, `\320\272` для символа «к»).

начиная с [версии 1.5.3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.3.txt) это поведение можно изменить с помощью [конфигурационного параметра](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) `core.quotepath` (принимает значения `true/false` или `on/off`).

для отключения такого преобразования только в текущем хранилище выполните:

```
$ git config core.quotepath false
```

для глобального отключения добавьте опцию `--global`:

```
$ git config --global core.quotepath false
```