# Кодировка имен файлов git bash

Tags: git

При работе в git bash имена файлов где присутствуют русские буквы выводятся вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что сделать что бы корректно имена файлов выводились?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русификация git в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770949/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-git-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо

Comment: Как второй вариант http://pr0git.blogspot.com/2015/02/git_4.html