# Как удалить файлы с нечитабельными именами?

Tags: ssh, shell

Загрузил на хостинг архив через FTP менеджер Filezilla. Распаковал его командой unzip через командную строку. При этом русские названия файлов превратились в кракозябры.

Теперь я не могу их удалить, не могу переименовать. 
SSH менеджер PuTTY вообще не видит эти файлы. Если удалить каталог, а потом создать его снова - то файлы никуда не исчезают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас немного файлов, то можете удалить их по номеру [inode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (их индексному дескриптору). Что бы узнать это номер выполните команду:

```
ls -i
```

А для удаления используйте такую команду:

```
find . -i <номер_inode> -delete
```

Если же вы хотите преобразовать имена этих файлов в нормальный вид, то воспользуйтесь командой convmv с примерно таким синтаксисом:

```
convmv -r -f <исходная_кодировка> -t <нужная_кодировка> .
```

Первый параметр - рекурсивно пройтись по указанному пути. Второй - исходная кодировка, в которой имена файлов находятся в данный момент. Третий - та кодировка, в которую нужно перевести имена файлов. Если результат вас устроит, то добавьте параметр --notest, т. к. по-умолчанию convmv лишь показывает преобразования, которые выполнит, но не выполняет фактическое преобразование.

Так же, в качестве дополнения, хочу сказать что произошло это скорее всего потому, что хостинг, на который вы загружали файлы, использует Linux и, следовательно, кодировку UTF-8. У вас же, скорее всего, имена файлов кодированы в CP-1251 (во всяком случае аналогичные случаи, которые мне попадались, были связаны именно с этим).

Answer (score 1):

как обращаться к файлам/каталогам, имена которых не получается ввести с клавиатуры, изложено, например, в четвёртом пункте этого ответа: [Ubuntu перейти в папку с названием на русском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451154/178576).

сначала имеет смысл проверить, например, программой *ls*, правильно ли вы указываете параметр `Ч` (номер файла/каталога в нумерованный выдаче):

```
$ ls "$(ls | sed -n Чp)"
```

эта команда должна вернуть имя этого файла/каталога.

а затем удалите программой *rm*:

```
$ rm "$(ls | sed -n Чp)"
```

если это каталог, а не файл, то понадобится ещё опция `-r` («рекурсивно»):

```
$ rm -r "$(ls | sed -n Чp)"
```

---

таким же образом можно и переименовать. с помощью программы *mv*:

```
$ mv "$(ls | sed -n Чp)" новое-имя
```