# Telnet: ввод кириллических символов после установки связи с сервером

Tags: linux, windows, putty, telnet

Уважаемые, подскажите, я уж не знаю где искать-смотреть. После установки связи telnet-ом с удаленным сервером, захожу в папку `cd /shared/Video` где мне необходимо в свою очередь зайти в папку с русскоязычным названием - переключаюсь на русскую раскладку - вместо русских букв идут \число\число (слэш-число). Причем сам вывод кириллических папок и файлов корректен, но `cd папка-по-русски` не получается. Подскажите, как включить возможность ввода кириллических символов? Пробовал и под линуксом и под Виндой - одинаково. Юзаю Putty, но пытался и через ПауэрШелл и через cmd->telnet - все одно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451145/178576

Comment: Если Вы соединяетесь через Putty, то проверьте, что у Вас задано в настройках сессии "Window/Translation/Remote character set".