# Открыть файл со спецсимволами в имени

Tags: linux, файлы

У есть файл с именем `:~/`.

Я не могу открыть этой файл `cat ':~/'`. Разные способы попробовал, но результата нет.

Как его открыть?

Кстати только *sh* работает, *bash* ограничено.

В папке такие файлы:

```
~ $ ls
#~o         :'(         :~#         :~E         =)          XD
$diary.txt  :(          :~&         :~J         =8)         X~(
(*v*)       :)          :~(         :~P         =D          X~p
(.V.)       :*          :~)         :~Q         =O          ^_^
(~:         :*)         :~)(~:      :~o         =P          |~O
(~}{~)      :>          :~)*        :~|         =^.^=       ~,~
)~:         :P          :~*         :~∕         =~O         ~:0
*<:o)       :S          :~>         ;)          >:)
*~*         :_(         :~@         ;~)         B~)
-$          :o          :~B         <:3)~       O.o
8~)         :o3         :~D         =(          O:~)
```

Comment: Попробуй cat ???

Comment: не помогло cat ':~/' , cat ":~/" cat {:~/} cat (:~/) все все делал не удалось

Comment: `cat ???` что я не понятно написал?

Comment: Можно cat ?~? попробовать

Comment: Символ `/` недопустим в имени файла во всех современных ОС, так что вы нас обманываете

Comment: в папке #~o         :'(         :~#         :~E         =)          XD
$diary.txt  :(          :~&         :~J         =8)         X~(
(*v*)       :)          :~(         :~P         =D          X~p
(.V.)       :*          :~)         :~Q         =O          ^_^
(~:         :*)         :~)(~:      :~o         =P          |~O
(~}{~)      :>          :~)*        :~|         =^.^=       ~,~

Comment: )~:         :P          :~*         :~∕         =~O         ~:0
*<:o)       :S          :~>         ;)          >:)
*~*         :_(         :~@         ;~)         B~)
-$          :o          :~B         <:3)~       O.o
8~)         :o3         :~D         =(          O:~)
такие файлы есть мне именно нужно открыть :~/ этой файл я написал cat??? не понятные символы вышли

Comment: `:~∕ ` и `:~/` это не одно и то же. `cat ':~∕'` должен отлично работать

Comment: https://ibb.co/rwX9KW1

Comment: смотрите картинку все видно

Comment: @RahimjonMuhamedov выделите команду `cat ':~∕'` в этом моём комментарии, нажмите правую кнопку мыши, выберите «Копировать», перейдите в терминал, нажмите правую кнопку мыши, выберите «Вставить» и нажмите Enter

Comment: @andreymal  спасибо помогло я так рад )))

Comment: @RahimjonMuhamedov повторюсь, `/` и `∕` это РАЗНЫЕ символы. Вы пытались вводить `/`, а нужно было вводить `∕`. Из моего комментария вы скопировали правильный символ, потому и помогло

Comment: да я не знал про это спасибо теперь буду знать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451154/178576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Символ `/` запрещён в имени в большинстве современных ОС, поэтому файл `:~/` существовать не может в принципе.

Вместо этого у вас существует файл `:~∕` — в нём используется другая косая черта.

Да, это две РАЗНЫЕ косые черты, несмотря на то, что в терминале они выглядят одинаково:

- `/` [U+002F SOLIDUS](https://unicode-table.com/ru/002F/) — косая черта, которая в именах не бывает
- `∕` [U+2215 DIVISION SLASH](https://unicode-table.com/ru/2215/) — это **знак деления**, который похож на косую черту

Соответственно, если вместо косой черты использовать знак деления, то команда `cat ':~∕'` отлично работает.

Answer (score 3):

копия [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451154/178576) (с заменой «каталог» → «файл») на по сути аналогичный вопрос:

1. запустите (предварительно установив, если не установлен, и есть такая возможность) какой-нибудь файловый менеджер: `mc`, `lfm`, `vifm`, `ranger` и т.п.
2. если установлен `vim` (не `vi`!) и надо отредактировать какой-то файл, то можно им и воспользоваться как файловым менеджером: `vim .` — программа запустится в режиме [*netrw*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075) (по умолчанию этот скрипт, вроде бы, установлен в *ubuntu*), где можно будет «перейти» к любому файлу/каталогу.

   нажатие <kbd>enter</kbd> будет интерпретировано для каталога — как `cd`, для файла — открытие его для редактирования.
3. если установлен `emacs`, можно воспользоваться его пакетом [*dired* — directory editor](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html).
4. на самый крайний (зато абсолютно универсальный) случай можно воспользоваться конструкцией `cat -- "$(...)"`, где вместо `...` должна идти команда, возвращающая имя нужного файла (кавычки нужны для тех случаев, когда в названии файла есть пробелы, а `--` — на случай, если имя файла начинается с дефиса).

   это может быть, например, команда `ls | sed -n 2p`, где `2` — номер нужного файла в выдаче `ls`.

   посмотреть пронумерованную выдачу `ls` можно, например, так:

   ```
   $ ls | nl
        1  acpi
        2  adduser.conf
        3  adjtime
        4  alternatives
        5  anacrontab
   ...
   ```

   т.е., для просмотра файла `adduser.conf` надо выполнить:

   ```
   $ cat -- "$(ls | sed -n 2p)"
   ```

Comment: Кстати, стоит добавить `--` после `cd`/`ls`/`cat`, иначе обратиться к файлу/каталогу, начинающемуся с дефиса, будет проблематично

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92932/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 1):

Кто-то весело поразвлекался :). Попробуйте использовать экранирование. Пишите символы через . Например (\~}{\~) вместо (~}{~) и т.п.
Единственное - символ '/' - его не должно быть, это зарезервированный символ, либо используется похожий спецсимвол (там есть один) или же это вообще каталог, который записывается также как и /usr/